# Rewriting urls in django and multi-tenancy

Tags: django, multi-tenant

i am writing a e-commerce application where different people can have stores with urls like this: www.store-one.saas.com, www.store-two.saas.com, and so on.

These domains have to be generated automatically when a user signs up for store.

I have read somewhere that www.saas.com/store-one can be rewritten as store-one.saas.com (ofcourse, they din told me how :( ).

Is it possible and how it can be done, how can i achieve it in production and with my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like [django-subdomains](http://django-subdomains.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) maybe.

Comment: documentation and english of this app sucks pretty bad .. anything else that can be understood ?